# Adding keys and values to a dictionary from two separate lists of same size

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have two lists, for example:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5]
```

and

```
B = [23, 34, 44, 43, 32]
```

I have initialized an empty dictionary

```
D = {}
```

I want to pick an element from A as key and pick the corresponding element from B as value. For example the dictionary should look like:

```
D = {1: 23, 2: 34, 3: 44, 4:43, 5:32}
```

So far, I have done the following:

```
D = {}
for k in A:
   for j in B:
       D[k] = j
print("D is", D)
```

This only gives me an output as follows:

```
D = {1: 32, 2: 32, 3: 32, 4:32, 5:32}
```

For some reason, it only pulls the last value from B which is not desirable. Please help.

Comment: "For some reason" -> The reason is because for every one value `k`, you run `D[k] = j` `len(B)` times. Of those times, only the last one matters, since each prior assignment will be overwritten by the next

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks for mentioning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ShadowRanger's solution

```py
d = dict(zip(A, B))
```

For the second question, assuming you have a list A with length `m`. The `for` loop will run `m * m` times. In the last `m` running, it will assign 32 which is the last element in the `B` to every key in `D`.

Comment: No need for a no-op comprehension; `dict(zip(A, B))` would do the job (as the top answer on the duplicate covers).

Comment: great idea, didn't know this would work.